# Setter based on MultipleBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

My model have two independent properties:

```
enumType DataType
SomeSpec DataSpec
```

based on value of `DataType` I would like to interpretate the DataSpec accordantely

```
<ContentControl DataContext ="{Binding}">
    <MultiBinding Converter ="{StaticResource DataContentConverter}">
        <Binding Path ="DataType"/>
        <Binding Path ="DataSpec"/>
    </MultiBinding>


    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType ="ContentControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding ="{Binding DataType}" Value ="Image">
                    <Setter Property ="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Image Source ="{Binding Image, Mode = OneWay}"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>

</ContentControl>
```

I am using the following converter implementation

```
public class DataViewConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] as enumType == null) return null;


        var selectedType = (enumType)values[0];
        var selectedObject = (SomeSpec)values[1];

        switch (selectedType )
        {
            case enumType.Thumbnail:
            case enumType.DisplayImage:
                {


                    return new DataContent
                               {
                                   DataType = ReducedDataType.Image,
                                   Image = SelectedObject.GetBitmapImage()
                               };
                }

            case ...

            default:
                {
                    return new DataContent
                               {
                                   DataType = ReducedDataType.Unknown,
                                   Text = "Content Viewer is not implemented!"
                               };
                }
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[] {};
    }
}
```

Implementing this I expect to see an image in my window, but instaed of it I only see a text **MyNameSpace.DataContent**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your DataTrigger's binding is being based off the ContentControl's DataContext.

```
<DataTrigger Binding ="{Binding DataType}" Value ="Image">
```

So, it is looking at ContentControl.DataContext.DataType.

I think what you want is for it to look at the DataType property of the ContentControl's Content. Try changing the DataTrigger to this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding ="{Binding Content.DataType, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value ="Image">
```

So now it is looking at ContentControl.Content.DataType. The RelativeSource part directs the binding to the ContentControl instead of ContentControl.DataContext.

Comment: Thanks you assumption has worked! Could display my image after your modification in <Data Trigger> and in <Image> tags. ne value of image tag is <Image Source ="{Binding Content.Image, Mode = OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>